# JavaScript : Make an array of value pairs form an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

Is there an elegant, functional way to turn this array:

`[ 1, 5, 9, 21 ]`

into this

`[ [1, 5], [5, 9], [9, 21] ]`

I know I could `forEach` the array and collect the values to create a new array. Is there an elegant way to do that in `_.lodash` without using a `forEach`?

Comment: why do you want this ? what's your goal ?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk. BTW, name of the operation is *usually* called `partition`, that link was the first google hit for 'lodash partition array'.

Comment: @niceman - the function would best be called 'adjacent pairs' - I've used that concept before.  Jared Smith - that's not the same.  Look at OP's example

Comment: @aaaaaa you're right, I didn't look closely enough at the desired output.

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973278/iterate-an-array-as-a-pair-current-next-in-javascript

Comment: @TreeNguyen that's not an exact duplicate but a similar question, that question wants just to iterate, OP here wants to return a new array

Comment: @Norris - keep in mind this is low-enough level functionality that you shouldn't be terribly concerned about readability (unless you're just trying to learn).  It's something you'd wrap in an intuitive function name, write tests for, and call it good.

Comment: @aaaaaa Yeah, I'm always trying to learn, so doing things the hard/readable way is the path I'm on. Otherwise - the ramda solution would work out just flawlessly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could map a spliced array and check the index. If it is not zero, take the predecessor, otherwise the first element of the original array.

```js
var array = [1, 5, 9, 21],
    result = array.slice(1).map((a, i, aa) => [i ? aa[i - 1] : array[0], a]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An even shorter version, as suggested by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi):

```js
var array = [1, 5, 9, 21],
    result = array.slice(1).map((a, i) => [array[i], a]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the cleanest way apart from using Ramda.

Comment: Why not just `(a, i) => [array[i], a]`?

Answer (score 5):

A fast approach using `map` would be:

```js
const arr = [ 1, 5, 9, 21 ];

const grouped = arr.map((el, i) => [el, arr[i+1]]).slice(0, -1);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Still most readable, can also be understood by other teammates.

Comment: @Norris I have finally removed the `pop` instruction. More elegant code now.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done with `array.reduce`. What the following does is use an array as aggregator, skips the first item, then for each item after that pushes previous item and the current item as a pair to the array.

```js
const arr = [ 1, 5, 9, 21 ];
const chunked = arr.reduce((p, c, i, a) => i === 0 ? p : (p.push([c, a[i-1]]), p), []);

console.log(chunked);
```

An expanded version would look like:

```js
const arr = [1, 5, 9, 21];
const chunked = arr.reduce(function(previous, current, index, array) {
  if(index === 0){
    return previous;
  } else {
    previous.push([ current, array[index - 1]]);
    return previous;
  }
}, []);

console.log(chunked);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use another functional library 'ramda', [aperture](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#aperture) is the function you're looking for.

Example usage taken from the ramda docs:

```
R.aperture(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); //=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
R.aperture(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); //=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
R.aperture(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); //=> []
```

Comment: Ramda actually looks really nice. And it does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I much prefer it over lodash/fp - but the maintainers are less active and spend a lot of time discussing as opposed to coding.  Choose your poison :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the current solutions, in a way, all look ahead or behind (`arr[i + 1]` or `arr[i - 1]`).

It might be useful to also explore an approach that uses `reduce` and an additional array, defined within a function's closure, to store a to-be-completed partition.

Notes:

- Not a one liner, but hopefully easy to understand
- `part` doesn't have to be an array when working with only 2 items, but by using an array, we extend the method to work for `n`-sized sets of items
- If you're not a fan of `shift`, you can use a combination of `slice` and redefine `part`, but I think it's safe here.
- partitions with a `length` less than the required number of elements are not returned

```js
const partition = partitionSize => arr => {
  const part = [];
  
  return arr.reduce((parts, x) => {
    part.push(x);
    
    if (part.length === partitionSize) {
      parts.push(part.slice());
      part.shift();
    }
    
    return parts;
  }, []);
};

const makePairs = partition(2);
const makeTrios = partition(3);

const pairs = makePairs([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
const trios = makeTrios([1,2,3,4,5,6]);


console.log("partition(2)", JSON.stringify(pairs));
console.log("partition(3)", JSON.stringify(trios));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows with just a sinle liner of `.reduce()` with no initial;

```js
var arr = [ 1, 5, 9, 21 ],
  pairs = arr.reduce((p,c,i) => i == 1 ? [[p,c]] : p.concat([[p[p.length-1][1],c]]));
console.log(pairs);
```

Comment: That doesn't work on empty arrays. Why not just use an initial argument? It's an even shorter oneliner.

Comment: @Bergi Yes of course obviously if you don't want to fall into the pit of "Reduce of empty array with no initial value"  you better take precautions.. but this one is obviously a mock up pseudo code. However the main problem is basically when the input is `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is an elegant way, programmatically, but, mathematically I can't help seeing that each new pair has an index difference of 1 from the original array.

If you (later) have the need to turn your array `[ 1, 5, 9, 21, 33 ]` into `[ [1, 9], [5, 21], [9, 33] ]`, you can use the fact that the difference between the indices is 2.

If you create code for the index difference of 1, extending this would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's `slide` which has two parameters to control the size of the slice and how many elements are dropped between slices

`slide` differs from other answers here by giving you these control parameters. other answers here are limited to producing only a slices of 2, or incrementing the slice by 1 each time

```js
// take :: (Int, [a]) -> [a]
const take = (n, xs) =>
  xs.slice(0, n)

// drop :: (Int, [a]) -> [a]
const drop = (n, xs) =>
  xs.slice(n)
  
// slice :: (Int, Int, [a]) -> [[a]]
const slide = (m, n, xs) =>
  xs.length > m
    ? [take(m, xs), ...slide(m, n, drop(n, xs))]
    : [xs]
    
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

// log helper improves readability of output in stack snippet
const log = x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x))

log(slide(1, 1, arr))
// [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]

log(slide(1, 2, arr))
// [[0],[2],[4],[6]]

log(slide(2, 1, arr))
// [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]

log(slide(2, 2, arr))
// [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6]]

log(slide(3, 1, arr))
// [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]

log(slide(3, 2, arr))
// [[0,1,2],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]

log(slide(3, 3, arr))
// [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6]]
```

If for some reason you didn't want `slide` to include *partial* slices, (slices smaller than `m`), we could edit it as such

```
// slice :: (Int, Int, [a]) -> [[a]]
const slide = (m, n, xs) =>
  xs.length > m
    ? [take(m, xs), ...slide(m, n, drop(n, xs))]
    : [] // <- return [] instead of [xs]

log(slide(2, 2, arr))
// now prints: [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]
// instead of: [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```