# Error when comparing an object with itself

Tags: javascript

I'm trying compare an value with the next value in the array, but when the loop is finished, the code that is after is not executed.

```
var json = [{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3},{'id':4},{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':5}];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    if(json[i].id == json[i+1].id){
        console.log("Equal");
    }
}

console.log('Something'); //This code is not executed
```

I realized that the problem is this part `[i+1]`. When I remove the number `1`, the code is executed normally.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The index `i + 1` will be out-of-bounds at the end.

Comment: in the `for` you should loop until `i < json.length - 1`

Comment: In your head, try stepping through the loop one iteration at a time. What happens when `i` is 1 less than the array's length? `json[i+1]` will be undefined. If the array length is 3, then `i+1` will be `3`. `json[3]` is `undefined`, so you can't get the `id` from `json[3]`.

Comment: Why downvoting the question?

Comment: A look into the browser console would have given you a lead already.

Comment: @OlivierKrull: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_ < That's what the downvote button says on its tooltip.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973278/iterate-an-array-as-a-pair-current-next-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your loop condition as `i < json.length-1` instead of `i < json.length` as having `i < json.length` as a condition will raise error of:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

And terminate the process so you do not get the last `console.log()`

```js
var json = [{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3},{'id':4},{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':5}];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length-1; i++){
    if(json[i].id == json[i+1].id){
        console.log("Equal");
    }
}

console.log('Something');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add this condition in your if statement:

```
var json = [{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3},{'id':4},{'id':4},{'id':5},{'id':5}];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length ; i++) {
    if ((i+1) < json.length  && json[i].id == json[i+1].id) {
        console.log("Equal");
    }
}

console.log('Something');
```